# Create multiple columns from one column (with the same data)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this column (similar but with a lot of more entries)

```
import pandas as pd
numbers = range(1,16)
sequence = []
for number in numbers:
    sequence.append(number)
df = pd.DataFrame(sequence).rename(columns={0: 'sequence'})
```

[image: df]

and I want to distribute the same values into lots of more columns periodically (and automatically) to get something like this (but with a bunch of values)

[image: df2]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.values.reshape` and desired rows and columns

```
pd.DataFrame(df.sequence.values.reshape(5, -1))
```

Comment: sorry but order is wrong; it increases row-wise.

Answer (score 3):

Use `reshape` with `5` for number of new rows, `-1` is for count automatically number of columns:

```
numbers = range(1,16)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(numbers).reshape(-1, 5).T)
    
print (df)
   0   1   2
0  1   6  11
1  2   7  12
2  3   8  13
3  4   9  14
4  5  10  15
```

If length of values in `range` cannot be filled to `N` rows here is possible   solution:

```
L = range(1,22)
N = 5
filled = 0
arr = np.full(((len(L) - 1)//N + 1)*N, filled)

arr[:len(L)] = L
df = pd.DataFrame(arr.reshape((-1, N)).T)
print(df)
   0   1   2   3   4
0  1   6  11  16  21
1  2   7  12  17   0
2  3   8  13  18   0
3  4   9  14  19   0
4  5  10  15  20   0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like to reshape after reading dataframe then

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(5,-1))
```

Comment: sorry but order is wrong; it increases row-wise.

Answer (score 1):

```
num_cols = 3

result = pd.DataFrame(df.sequence.to_numpy().reshape(-1, num_cols, order="F"))
```

for a given number of columns, e.g., 3 here, reshapes `df.sequence` to `(total_number_of_values / num_cols, num_cols)` where first shape is inferred with `-1`. The `F`ortran order matches the structure so that numbers are "going down first",

to get

```
>>> result

   0   1   2
0  1   6  11
1  2   7  12
2  3   8  13
3  4   9  14
4  5  10  15
```

If `num_cols = 5`, then

```
>>> result

   0  1  2   3   4
0  1  4  7  10  13
1  2  5  8  11  14
2  3  6  9  12  15
```